# Problem in using dynamic C++ libraries in Python code

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I  am trying to call a C++  library inside a python code and i am using the ctypes python library but i keep getting the following error:
*Unable to load the system C library
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.*
here is the python code:

```
import sys 
import ctypes, ctypes.util

# Find the library and load it
mylib_path = ctypes.util.find_library("./mylib")
print(mylib_path)
if not mylib_path:
    print("Unable to find the specified library.")
    sys.exit()
try:
    mylib = ctypes.CDLL(mylib_path)
except OSError:
    print("Unable to load the system C library")
    sys.exit()
print(mylib.add(5,4))
```

The exeption thrown:
Unable to load the system C library
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

Comment: Could you print the OSError code/exception message?

Comment: You should let the exception thats being thrown instead of your (dummy) text. Also *CTypes* stand for ***C*** (**not *C++***) types.

Comment: What OS and compiler do you use? Did you compile the C++ library yourself? If so, what are the compilation commands?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. The  C++ library was compiled by me using visual studio, as for the code here is the source.https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/07/18/python-using-c-cpp-libraries-ctypes/

Comment: Please post your exact code and compilation commands directly in the question. Also please be aware that `except OSError:
    print("Unable to load the system C library")` is **bad code** and you should follow people who showcase such code at your own risk.

Comment: Codes and commands are taken from the website https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/07/18/python-using-c-cpp-libraries-ctypes/ under the "section Building a shared C library and using the library from Python" as well as the compiling command.